# Drawing custom page border with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, border

The result I want to get is something like this

[image: bordered]

I attempted to use the `crop` package, but I keep getting an `Undefined control sequence. <argument> \trimtop` error so I want to try and get that result with `tikz`, but superimposing the image seemed like overkill, so is there an easier way to get this layout?

Comment: please provide us with what you've tried so far. some document classes contain commands for cropping marks (`memoir` for example). welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Hi, I also can't use memoir because it breaks too many things. The document class I'm using uses the report class and is a custom one made by the university.

Comment: i just blindly guessing, what you use. without any information about your document i deeply doubt that anyone here can help you. sorry, at least my crystal ball is broken :-). you can use `tikz`, see options `remember picture` and `overlay` (for one page only, i'm afraid).

Comment: You can use the geometry to show crop marks, but you need to define a layout smaller than the page.

Comment: Or you can use the `background` package. Maybe. That is, depending on other things, you might be able to use this or it might not work. You'll just have to try stuff since you haven't shared any relevant information here.